How to add line segments with different colors to a 'ID2D1GeometrySink' interface?
I would like to use the AddLine method of the interface ID2D1GeometrySink repeatedly, but defining the color of each segment at each consecutive inclusion. I imagine that 'closing' the action of adding line segments and opening it again just to change the color of a line segment would make the process slow. Is there a way to perform this operation quickly and efficiently?

May I ask why this question is tagged as [tag:mfc]? DirectX isn't MFC-based. If you are going to use it in an MFC application, this makes little to no difference, as MFC is largely a wrapper for Win32. I would rather tag it as Win32 or WinAPI, along with C++ (I guess this is the language you are going to use). Maybe you should use the "mfc" tag if you have troubles integrating it into your MFC application, presenting us some code (your attempted implementation). This question is [tag:direct2d]-only basically. At least add the tags I proposed above, more people will likely read it.

@ConstantineGeorgiou, as you recommeded, I 've removed the tag MFC.

Geometry does not have such attributes as color or style. Those are provided when you draw or fill it, with DrawGeometry/FillGeometry. So no, it's not possible to set color for the geometry segments at all.
If you need to switch styles or colors you'll need to have multiple geometries, and several draw/fill calls. It's possible to pack those in a single command list.
